# How to download xml file from server without http headers

Tags: android, http, network-protocols

I'm trying to download an xml file to parse from a server, but the server doesn't send HTTP headers, just the xml text.  I have tried almost every method of downloading files with a URL that I can find, yet everything gives me an I/O Exception.  I can load the file into a WebView, but I can't download the file myself.

How can I open a connection and download the xml file with no HTTP headers?

EDIT:
Still giving me an I/O Exception, here is the code I'm using:

```
    private class UpdateTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids ) {
        String url = "http://192.168.1.92/state.xml";
        try{
            //get XML Pull parser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
            //factory.setValidating(false);
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();        

            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
            DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

            if(response == null) return null;

            HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream inStream  = null;
            StringBuilder sb      = null;
            if (httpEntity == null) return null;

            try {
                inStream = httpEntity.getContent();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8"));
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;

                while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }

                inStream.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                }
                String xmlString = sb.toString();

                xpp.setInput(new StringReader(xmlString));
                int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

                String name = null;
                String text = null;
                while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) { // <name>
                        name = xpp.getName();
                        System.out.println("got name: " + name);
                    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {// </name> (xpp.getName();
                    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) { // <>text</>
                        text = xpp.getText();
                        System.out.println("got text: " + text);

                    }
                    eventType = xpp.next();
                }
                finished = true;
            }catch(MalformedURLException e){
                System.out.println("Malformed URL");
            }catch(IOException e){
                System.out.println("IO Exception updating " + name + " at address: " + address);
            }catch(XmlPullParserException e){
                System.out.println("XML Pull Parser Error updating " + name + " at address: " + address);
            }catch(Exception e){
            }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Gives me an I/O Exception every time.  However, if I point it to a server that provides an HTTP header, it downloads just fine.  The servers are devices that we make in-house, and the older units didn't provide HTTP headers when you request the state.xml file, so I need to be able to work with both.

Comment: Find/read some articles about how to ask questions. Your question should be specific as much as you can. You should provide as much information about problem as you can.

Comment: If you feed http://192.168.1.92/state.xml to your browser and it returns you xml, then put a breakpoint on a first line in your try section and find out what causes the exception or post your LogCat here

Comment: The browser returns the xml page fine.  iOS also connects and loads fine, and WebViews also display the XML.  In the code, it throws an I/O Exception when I open an InputStream, or in this case when I do client.execute(httpGet);  My logcat just returns the System.out.println("I/O Exception"); even with strictmode on.  Is there a way to get a more detailed error report?

Comment: Difficult to say why, I will try to reproduce in my environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open my own socket, create an HTTP Get request, and then remove the HTTP headers for servers that DO have headers.

```
        public String getData(){
        String returnData = "";
        String requestmsg = "GET /state.xml HTTP/1.0\r\n";
        requestmsg += "Connection: close\r\n";
        if(cpPassword != null)
            requestmsg += "Authorization: Basic " + Base64.encodeBytes(("admin:" + cpPassword).getBytes()) + "\r\n";
        requestmsg += "\r\n";

        int intPort = 80;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        BufferedReader dis = null;
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(address, intPort);
            String data = "";
            socket.setSoTimeout(3000); //timeout after 2 seconds
            dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            dos.write(requestmsg.getBytes());

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            while ((data = dis.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(data);
            }
            returnData = sb.toString();
            if(returnData.length() == 0)
                return "";
            int xmlIndex = returnData.indexOf( "<?xml" );
            returnData = returnData.substring(xmlIndex);
            return returnData;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error Getting Data From Socket", e);
            returnData = "";
        }finally{
            try{
                if(socket!=null)
                    socket.close();
            }catch(IOException e){
                Log.e("ClientActivity", "C: Error Closing Socket", e);
            }
        }
        return returnData;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at documentation how to properly configure connection, briefly you'll have something like this:

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(mServerUrl);
DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

if(response == null) return;

HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
InputStream inStream  = null;
StringBuilder sb      = null;
if (httpEntity == null) return;

try {
    inStream = httpEntity.getContent();
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inStream, "UTF-8"));
    sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;

while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}

inStream.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
String xmlString = sb.toString();
```